# How to find clusters of a set of points in n-dimensional space that are furthest from unwanted points

Tags: machine-learning, computational-geometry, neural-networks, statistics, clustering

I have a list of 25 points and their coordinates in a 512-dimensional space. I have 8 target points and 17 points I need to avoid (the 17 points to avoid also have differences in priority of how important it is to avoid them). I want to find the smallest number of clusters that group together the 8 target points (in groups of 2-8), while maximizing the distance away from the unwanted points - it's also important that not only do the desired points making the cluster have to be far away from the unwanted points, the interior points of the shape made by the cluster also need to be maximally distant from the unwanted points.

My current train of thought is as follows, but I'm open to suggestions (psuedocode):

```
for combination in all possible combinations of 2-8 target points
  combination.score = 0
  for each unwanted point
    combination.score += distance(combination, unwanted point) * unwanted point.priority
```

Then I'd use a simple greedy algorithm to find the groupings with the highest scores that contain all the desired points. The one outstanding question I haven't quite figured out yet is how to find the distance between an arbitrary point and a shape made up of n points in 512-dimensional space.

For context, the 512-dimensional coordinates are coming from a Tensorflow model, which I mention because I'm aware of machine learning techniques for reducing dimensionality, but am unsure of what approaches would be appropriate here or what to look for in comparing those/if that would help reduce the complexity of this problem.

[This is the Tensorflow model in question if anybody is curious](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1)

Comment: Unfortunately programming questions are off-topic here. You can try [datascience.se](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) instead. If you ask your question there, please remove it here, to prevent duplicates.

Comment: I feel like this isn’t a programming question - I posted it here specifically because I’m looking for guidance on relevant algorithms to look further into. I only linked to the Tensorflow model to provide more context

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "the largest clusters of words I want that exclude the unwanted words"?  It sounds like you want an algorithm to solve some task.  What are the inputs to that algorithm, and what are the conditions for a proposed output to be correct?

Comment: Questions specific to tensorflow are off-topic here. Questions requiring us to look at code are off-topic here.

Comment: Rephrased the question to make it more clear what I'm asking and to make it more clear that the Tensorflow link is just for additional context and not central to the question, as well as adding in my current thought process